# Reading a line whose contents depends on the first character

Tags: string, io, fortran, fortran90

In Fortran, what would be the practical way to read:

```
 A 1. 2. 3.
```

if the first character is an "A", but to not read the:

```
 Z
```

rest if the first character is a "Z" for example.

If I try to read the line at whole:

```
read(1,*)char, number1, number2, number3
```

then an error will occur if the numbers are missing. So I need a way to read an "A" stay on that line, and depending on the "A" or a "Z" read, if needed the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good trick you may not know. You can put a character variable in place where the unit number is in the read statement. You would be reading from the variable instead of the file.

Start by declaring a character variable long enough to read the longest line. Read the whole line into this variable. From the variable, read that first character. If it is an A, read in the numbers. It would look like this:

```
character*130 :: MyLine

read(1,'(a130)') MyLine
read(MyLine,*) char
if (char == 'A') then
   read(MyLine,*) char, number1, number2, number3
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always read the flag and use an expression in the iolist to determine whether you want to read any more stuff.
az.f90:

```
program az
   implicit none
   real number1, number2, number3
   character azflag
   integer iunit
   integer i
   open(newunit=iunit,file='az.txt',status='old')
   do
      number1 = -1
      number2 = -1
      number3 = -1
      read(iunit,*,end=10) azflag, (number1,number2,number3 &
         ,i=1,merge(1,0,any(azflag==['A','a'])))
      if(any(azflag==['A','a'])) then
         write(*,*) 'numbers read!'
      else
         write(*,*) 'nothing read'
      end if
      write(*,*) number1, number2, number3
   end do
10 continue
end program az
```

az.txt:

```
 A 1. 2. 3.
 Z
 a 4. 5. 6.
 z
```

Output:

```
 numbers read!
   1.000000       2.000000       3.000000
 nothing read
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000
 numbers read!
   4.000000       5.000000       6.000000
 nothing read
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight deviation from what you want would be to replace the first letter by the number of numbers to read, like

```
3 1. 2. 3.
0
2 3.14 -1.
```

Then if the maximum number of elements you want to read in each row is `nmax` then declare

```
integer::i,n
real(dimension=nmax)::number
```

and use

```
read(1,*) n, (number(i), i=1,n)
```

If you really want to keep using letters, you can hack something using `iachar()` to get the ASCII value of the character converted into the number of reals to read.